# Why does this greedy algorithm fail to accurately determine whether a graph is a perfect matching?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, greedy-algorithms, matching

I came across this problem in *Tim Roughgarden*'s course on *Coursera*:

> In this problem you are given as input a graph $T=(V,E)$ that is a
>   tree (that is, $T$ is undirected, connected, and acyclic). A perfect
>   matching of $T$ is a subset $F \subseteq E$ of edges such that every
>   vertex $v \in V$ is the endpoint of exactly one edge of $F$.
>   Equivalently, $F$ matches each vertex of $T$ with exactly one other
>   vertex of $T$. For example, a path graph has a perfect matching if and
>   only if it has an even number of vertices.
>
> Consider the following two algorithms that attempt to decide whether
>   or not a given tree has a perfect matching. The degree of a vertex in
>   a graph is the number of edges incident to it. (The two algorithms
>   differ only in the choice of $v$ in line 5.)

Algorithm **A**:

```
While T has at least one vertex:
  If T has no edges: 
    halt and output "T has no perfect matching."
  Else:
    Let v be a vertex of T with maximum degree.
    Choose an arbitrary edge e incident to v.
    Delete e and its two endpoints from T.
[end of while loop]
Halt and output "T has a perfect matching."
```

Algorithm **B**:

```
While T has at least one vertex:
  If T has no edges: 
    halt and output "T has no perfect matching."
  Else:
    Let v be a vertex of T with minimum non-zero degree.
    Choose an arbitrary edge e incident to v.
    Delete e and its two endpoints from T.
[end of while loop]
Halt and output "T has a perfect matching."
```

Now, the answer key says:

> Algorithm $A$ can fail, for example, on a three-hop path. Correctness of
>   algorithm $B$ can be proved by induction on the number of vertices in $T$.
>   Note that the tree property is used to argue that there must be a
>   vertex with degree $1$; if there is a perfect matching, it must include
>   the edge incident to this vertex.

However, I think I found a counter-example which shows that Algorithm **B** may not be correct. Am I missing something?  Consider the following graph (say $T$):

[image]

If we follow **B**:

**Step 1:** Let $v=3$ (all vertices have the same degree) and $e=(2,3)$. Remove $e$ along with vertices $3$ and $2$.

[image]

**Step 2:** Let $v=1$ and $e=(0,1)$. Remove $e$ along with vertices $0$ and $1$.

**Step 3:** No vertices are left. Hence we get the output: "T has a perfect matching."

But clearly, our original graph was not a perfect matching as all the nodes were of degree $3$.

**Note:** I assumed that *ties* are meant to be broken arbitrarily by the algorithm.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Consider the following two algorithms that attempt to decide whether or not a given **tree** has a perfect matching". [Your graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt4PJm.png) is NOT a tree as it has a cycle $0, 1, 2, 0$.

Furthermore, your graph does have a perfect matching. In fact, the edges $(2,3)$ and $(0,1)$ obtained by your step 1, 2 and 3 is a perfect matching. And hence, it is not true that "our original graph was not a perfect matching as all the nodes were of degree 3". Plenty of graphs whose nodes are all of degree 3 have a perfect matching.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithms are understated: When a vertex is deleted, *all* edges incident to that vertex are also deleted, otherwise we're left with dangling edges.

Consider the path tree $ A - B - C - D $. Algo A chooses vertex $ B $, and say, edge $ (B, C) $. After deleting vertices $ B $ and $ C $, and all the edges, we're left with vertices $ A $ and $ D $ with no edges. Algo A halts, and incorrectly declares that $ T $ doesn't have perfect matching (it does, $ \{ (A, B ), (C, D) \} $).

Lets prove the correctness of algo B by induction. For $ \lvert V \rvert = 1 $, it correctly identifies that $ T $ doesn't have perfect matching. For $ \lvert V \rvert = 2 $, it correctly identifies that $ T $ has perfect matching. Clearly, for $ T $ to have perfect matching, $ \lvert V \rvert $ must be even.
Assume algo B works for $ \lvert V \rvert = k $. Let us add a new vertex $ v $ and a new edge $ (v, w) $ to $ T $, where $ w $ is some existing vertex in $ T $. Clearly, for $ T $ to have perfect matching, it must include edge $ (v, w) $ (since that's the only way to match vertex $ v $). By construction, algo B picks $ v $ and removes edge $ (v, w) $ in some iteration, leaving $ \lvert V \rvert = k - 1 $, which by inductive hypothesis, is correctly solved by algo B.

Therefore, algo B is correct.

The solutions to the other questions from the course are available on [my blog](https://blog.asarkar.org/algorithms-design-analysis-2/).